# Overlay .mxd file to ArcGIS in Android Studio

Tags: arcgis-android, indoor

I'm trying to overlay a floor plan of a building to the app I've built using the site:

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/add-geocoding-to-your-app.htm

I have path segments and nodes drawn inside the image that I would like to be able to use my phone to navigate from my GPS location to whatever room number I specify (which has a node). I can't publish the file to any ArcGIS server because I have signed an NDA concerning the CAD files for the floor plans.

In short, how can I overlay the .mxd file onto the ArcGIS map in my Android application?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you cannot overlay a *.mxd file using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android.  Using the current version of the SDK, [v100.0.0](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/), with ArcGIS Pro you can [create a mobile map package](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-mobile-map-package.htm) and consume that in the SDK.  You would have to convert your CAD files to feature layer/data in ArcMap so it can be used in your mobile map package and coupled with network data in the mobile map package to navigate.